# How to post feeds to twitter?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to post some text automatically to my application twitter account. I create an account for that and take all the needed information and write a php code for it. it is simple code:
I made it just to test the post ability :

```
    <?php
    require_once 'oauth/twitteroauth.php';
    $message = "hiiiiiii"; #actual message to twitter

    define("CONSUMER_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");    
    define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    define("OAUTH_SECRET", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
print_r($connection);

    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
//print_r($content);


    $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
   ?>
```

I get the information from the account so i think the connection is working but why i can not post any thing? i tried to post this message but after executing this code nothing happened on my twitter no new tweet is shown????

$connection->post is a method :

```
 /**
   * POST wrapper for oAuthRequest.
   */
  function post($url, $parameters = array()) {
    $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters);
    if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
    }
    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: what does `$connection->post` return

Comment: it is a method in the class that i use. I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

My first port of call if you are able to receive information from the account using those credentials, would be that your app has read **AND** write (posting) permissions:

> Go to dev.twitter.com/apps. Select your app, then under 'settings' -->
>   'application type' you will find what you need.

Although that didn't work, no matter what you changed in your code posting to your account through this app wouldn't work as that functionality was outside the permissions you set yourself. So now we know that you're able to post:

Change

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
```

To

```
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
```

Then see what the value of $result is. This might provide some clues

Ok so the response is telling you, you still don't have permissions, you need to regenerate your token and access credentials then update your code with them:

```
 define("CONSUMER_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");    
 define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 define("OAUTH_SECRET", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Those credentials still have the previous permissions attached to them, when you request new token, it will reference the new permissions and allow you to post.

Comment: I change the permission to read and write but i still can not post any tweet

Comment: I can not understand they said   "Error processing your OAuth request: Read-only application cannot POST"

Comment: I figured out the problem. I should generate a new token for the application after changing the permission from read to read and write. Thank u for your help